# What is the remainder when $3^{1264}$ is divided by 549?

Tags: number-theory

Please explain in detail.

I tried a lot by applying normal remainder theorem but I am not able to get anywhere.

Comment: Do u know modular arithematic?

Comment: No, but if you explain me, I am sure I will get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. $549=9\cdot61$, and $9$ and $61$ are mutually prime. So you can compute $3^{1264}\bmod 9$ and $3^{1264}\bmod 61$, then combine results using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT). The first of these is easy, for $3^2\equiv0\bmod9$. And the second one you can do by Fermat's little theorem, noting that $61$ is prime, so $3^{60}\equiv1\bmod 61$. Note that $1264=60\cdot21+4$ … so that $3^{1264}=3^{60\cdot21+4}=(3^{60})^{21}\cdot3^4\equiv3^4=81\bmod 61$. It seems more natural to reduce the last bit mod $61$ and get $20$, but by accident, $81$ is divisible by $9$, so we are saved from doing the last bit involving the CRT.

Comment: I know you asked for a detailed answer. I am sorry that I don't have the time for that. Maybe someone else will come up with more details for you.

Comment: No problem. If you or some one else can explain how did he apply Fermat's theorem on the second part, I will be thankful to him/her!

Comment: I appended a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $61$ is prime hence $\varphi(61)=60$ and $3$ and $61$ are relatively prime. By Euler's theorem, $3^{60}=1\pmod{61}$ hence $3^{1262}=9\cdot3^{60\cdot21}=9\pmod{61}$. Multiplying everything by $9$ yields $3^{1264}=9\cdot3^{1262}=9\cdot9\pmod{61\cdot9}$, that is, $3^{1264}=81\pmod{549}$.